# React.js: move element to its new position smoothly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-animations, jsx

I need to smoothly move an element from one position to another, whenever it renders somewhere else. Here's my simplified example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const SomeComponent = () => {
    const [isYes, setIsYes] = useState(true);

    return (
        <div>
            <div>Yes{isYes && <i>*</i>}</div>
            <div>No{!isYes && <i>*</i>}</div>
            <button onClick={() => setIsYes(!isYes)}>Toggle</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default SomeComponent;
```

Whenever the button is clicked, the asterisk toggles between `Yes*` and `No*`. I need this asterisk to move smoothly, in animated manner. I tried tricks with `useRef()` combined with `getBoundingClientRect()`, but I ended up having either buggy behavior or infinite rendering.

How should it be done properly? Or perhaps, is there a library to animate an element in cases like mine?

Comment: You could achieve with css actually. wrapp your asterisks inside a span, where you toggle visiblity property css based on your value. Then you add a transition on the element, like opacity, margin or whater. If you want to make. with opacity. if you want it to smoothly goes from left to right, assign a fixed width to the span elements and just transition with a margin left. That should do the trick. No need to apply so  much js logic

Comment: I want to move it smoothly, not just fade in and out. It's not as simple as it seems with React :(

Comment: what is smoothly

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial animated, so it goes in a line from point A to point B.

Comment: too much work - please explore this https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-2-animatesharedlayout-animate-between-different-components-dy0bv?from-embed

Comment: Did you try Portal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53595935/how-can-i-make-react-portal-work-with-react-hook

Comment: I had the same question once. What I did was I downloaded a css framework as Semantic UI React, afterwards I made a function which has the Semantic UI react animated component inside of it and returns it. 

Then based on ur condition (yes/no) you can use that function to fade smoothly in or out or whatever u would like to do because there are alot of animations you can use.

Comment: @MauricePheyton well, but how would it know the previous position? That's the main issue, it's not a simple matter of "animating" it.